# which dom element will work outside bootstrap dropdown-item to display an default image based on open dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

In my menu , i have two columns, one for submenu text and other for respective images. this portion is working fine. But i want to set a default image, which will display when user will not hover on any dropdown item or out of dropdown. but i have 2-3 dropdown menu. how to identify each individually. Thanks

```
code[https://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/4h7sgpdL/48/]
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right.

If you need a different default image for every main menu point, then append a url/image-path to the **li**-tag via **data-src** for example.

EDIT: something like this?

```
https://jsfiddle.net/2a3joxfz/7/
```

all **a-tags** got an **rel** attribute.

Comment: Hello brandt, please have a look on my fiddle for clear idea. I am using jquery it is working properly on submenu hover, but i have issues with default image which will specific based on  main menu. i am trying to do this by using mouseout from nav-item for all over the remaining section and navbar hover when it is on main menu... but it's look something wrong with code.. please run the code using some images.  https://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/4h7sgpdL/48/

Comment: @shreya_js: is this the solution for your problem?
    https://jsfiddle.net/2a3joxfz/7/

Or is there something more todo?

Comment: Thanks... but when you scroll your mouse over the hover and page, you'll get blank space meanwhile. i solved my problem using .parent().next().children() and it's work. but now the problem is i am changing the text under the photos using title... But i am looking for better alternatives.